# recent research work on computational homotopy/ persistent homotopy

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, topological-data-analysis

Persistent homology has been broadly used in topological data analysis since we have some ways to calculate them efficiently. However, homotopy is very different to compute so it is hard to use for computer scientists/ data analysts. Does anyone know if there is some recent work related to computational homotopy/ computational persistent homotopy that makes some progress in this field? I didn't find one myself, and I am very interested in the topic.

Thanks!

Comment: For computational homotopy I would start from papers with Marek Krčál as coauthor https://scholar.google.cz/citations?user=kiLJwOYAAAAJ&hl=en